# core data fetched properties and NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, fetched-property

I read this in the core data programming guide:

> In many cases, your initial fetch retrieves a starting node in the object graph and thereafter you do not execute fetch requests, you simply follow relationships.

This makes sense if everything is linked to one object.

However, say i have this object model and relationship

`Company (one to  many) Team (one to many) Employee (one to one) Role`

Say I load my Company at the start with a fetch request. I then have access to a set of Teams, and in each Team i have a set of Employees.

(this is all hypothetical, but my app follows the same model)

I want to load a UITableView that lists all Employees which have a Role of 'developer', and I want to do this using an NSFetchedResultsController.

I would like to create a fetched property on Company that returns all 'developers'. Which is easy enough.

How would I link this fetched property to NSFetchedResultsController ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understood your question, but if you want to use a NSFetchedResultsController with UITableView you have to use a NSFetchRequest, you cannot just follow relationship, which is use faulting.

It seems you already have a fetch request, for use it with a fetched controller you have to pass such request to the NSFetchedResultsController.

However you can get NSFetchedPropertyDescription by looking into the entity description, and its properties:

```
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = .....
```

Then you can call properties and cycle all the array until you find your property:

```
NSArray *allProperties = entityDescription.properties;
NSFetchedPropertiesDescription *myPropertyDescription;
for(NSPropertyDescription *propertyDescription in allProperties) {
  // find it by name or class
  if([propertyDescription isKindOfClass:[NSFetchedPropertyDescription class]])
    myPropertyDescription = (NSFetchedPropertyDescription*)propertyDescription;
}

NSFetchedRequest *fetchRequest = [myPropertyDescription fetchRequest];

        NSFetchedResultsController *myController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
                                                 initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                 managedObjectContext:myManagedObjectContext
                                                 sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                 cacheName:myCacheName];
```

I do not have my Mac right now so I cannot test for code validity, however it should be right.

Comment: Umm, this looks pretty interesting and might just be what I need. I shall be testing this tonight and will follow up with my results. Thanks.

Comment: Here is a more succinct way of what you are doing to get the fetch request from the property description: `NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Application"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:self.coreDataStack.managedObjectContext];
    
    NSFetchRequest *request = [entity valueForKeyPath:@"propertiesByName.usageMetricsForType.fetchRequest"];

Answer (score 3):

What the documentation is talking about is that you use a fetch to find a set of managed objects based on some attribute and then you find all the related objects by walking the relationships. This differers significantly from how you would find data in a relational database. Since relationships are hardcoded as the object graph is built, walking them is very, very fast compared to fetching and you can model arbitrary relationships.

You seldom, if ever, used fetched properties to find a managed object you could just walk to. Fetched properties are used to find objects you can't walk to such as objects stored in another persistent store file.

To walk relationships you use keypaths. E.g. to find all employees of a particular company in your model, you would use a key path of `teams.employees` and you would start with a particular company object. To find developers, you would walk the path to the `Role` attribute that holds the `developer` value, something like: `team.employees.role.roleType`.

In your particular case, if you want a table with all developers, you wouldn't set the fetch to the `Company` entity but to the `Employee` entity. The you would use a predicate with a keypath e.g. `role.roleType== developer`. If you wanted all the developers in a certain company you would use a predicate like: `role.roleType== developer AND team.company.name == aCompanyName.

However, it would be even better to adjust your model like this:

```
Company<-->>Team<-->>Employee<<-->Role
```

Now you have a `Role` entity that can attach the same role to many employees. Now you can fetch on the `Role` entity with a simple keypath of `roleType== developer` and you get one object back. Walking the `employees` relationship of `Role` would give you all developer employees.

The important thing to remember with Core Data is that the entities and their relationships are meant to simulate the real-world objects, events and conditions that your app deals with. You should set up the data model to as closely as possible represent those real-world things and the relationships between them. E.g. In the real world, `developer` is just one role so it should be represented by just one object in the object graph. In the real world, many employees could fulfill the role of developer so the relationship between `Employees` and `Roles` should be `Employee<<-->Role`.

The more closely your model simulates reality, the easier you app becomes to write in all regards.

Comment: Another interesting answer, because this is how I currently do it. But I'm feeling I need to use a fetched property. Mainly due to the statement i read in the core programming guide "In many cases, your initial fetch retrieves a starting node in the object graph and thereafter you do not execute fetch requests, you simply follow relationships." Also because I feel my code is full of NSFetchRequests that don't really need to be there because I can access them through the properties of one root object.

Comment: So what is wrong with adding a fetched property on Role that has a predicate in which roleName==developer - mainly to use as a easy way to access this? Would this be more efficient than building an NSFetchRequest?

Comment: You're misunderstanding the documentation. You don't build an object graph which has only one object your fetch. Instead an object graph is like a pile of bead necklaces where each bead is an object and the string is the relationship. You use a fetch to find a bead on each neckless and then you use follow the string to find the related beads. In other words, you total object graph is made up of many smaller graphs that don't necessarily connect to one another. You use fetches to grab one object in each small graph and then walk the relationships

Comment: Fetched properties don't update automatically like relationships. You have to manually refresh the object to get the fetch to run again. This make maintaining an accurate up to date graph difficult. Fetched properties should only be used when you can't use relationships.

Comment: Yeah, I've took your advice on board and steered away from them for now - as they are not quite what I need. Thanks. (marked the other as the answer, as it actually answers my final question of "How would I link this fetched property to NSFetchedResultsController ?"). Thanks for the advice.